# Define ah hash-based index in JDO

Tags: mysql, sql, google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-sql

I have a field that needs to be indexed. That field will be used only on equality filters and joins, so it would be more efficient to have it saved as an hash index. I can't find on the jdo documentation any standard way of doing this (which makes sense, since it's a very low-level thing). Is there any way to do this in datanucleus using POJO annotations?

Additional information: I'm using datanucleus to access a table in Google Cloud SQL, which is basically MySql. I would prefer JDO creating tables and indexes for me, instead of explicitly writing a CREATE TABLE in SQL with proper indexes specified (or a later CREATE INDEX).

**EDIT**

I know @Index annotation, but there seems to be no way to specify what kind of index do you want, and I think without specification MySql will create a BTREE based index, which is not what I want: I need to use hash based indexes (or to be convinced that BTREEs are more efficient of hashes on equality filters, but I don't think this is the case).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DataNucleus JDO then you don't seem to have looked far for the documentation - all JDO schema control is documented. Try this for indexes
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/orm/constraints.html

Comment: Actually I haven't searched in datanucleus documentation, but only JDO. Which is my fault. My other fault is that my question is not probably enough clear about the fact what I want is an hash-based index, and I'm going to improve the question right now.